# Configuring single Squid server using url query string

Tags: proxy, squid

Is it possible to use Squid as reverse proxy with multiple web servers based on a query string that is passed to squid proxy?

This is the example from Squid wiki:

- acl foo urlpath_regex ^/foo

  cache_peer ip.of.server1 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=server1
  cache_peer_access server1 deny foo

  cache_peer ip.of.server2 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=server2
  cache_peer_access server2 allow foo
  cache_peer_access server2 deny all

This requires me to setup acls per webserver that I want to have, for example:

- acl foo urlpath_regex ^/toserver1
- acl foo urlpath_regex ^/toserver2
- acl foo urlpath_regex ^/toserver3
- etc

I'd like to instead specify the webserver my reverse proxy should forward to using a url parameter. For example:

- http://myproxyserver.com/?webserver=server1.com&port=8000
- http://myproxyserver.com/?webserver=server2.com&port=8900
- etc

Is this possible in Squid?